# SnippetException: Cannot document response fields as the response body is empty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restdocs

Here is my Controller:

```
 @PostMapping("post")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('WRITE')")
public ResponseEntity<?> createPost(@RequestBody PostEntity postEntity) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(postService.createPost(postEntity), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Service :

```
 @Override
public Post createPost(PostEntity postEntity) {
    return postFactory.buildPost(postEntityRepository.save(postEntity));
}

//Post is Immutable class here
    public Post buildPost(PostEntity entity) {
        return new Post.Builder()
                .groupId(entity.getGroupEntity().getGroupId())
                .postedBy(entity.getPostedBy().getUsername())
                .postType(entity.getType())
                .postMedia(entity.getPostMedia())
                .postId(entity.getPostId())
                .build();
    }
```

Here is my mockMvc:

```
 @BeforeEach
public void setUp(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext,
                  RestDocumentationContextProvider restDocumentation) {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
            .alwaysDo(document("{method-name}",
                    preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()), preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())))
            .build();
}
```

Here is my Test:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api/post")
            .contentType(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON)
            .contextPath("/api")
            .content(this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(postEntity)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andDo(
                    document("{method-name}", preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
                            preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()),
                            requestFields(describeCreatePostRequest()),
                            responseFields(describePostEntityResult())
                    ));
```

Here is Post call:

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutablePost.class)
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutablePost.class)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Relation(value = "post", collectionRelation = "posts")
public interface Post {

    Long getPostId();

    String getPostType();

    String postedBy();

    @Nullable
    PostMedia postMedia();

    Long groupId();

    class Builder extends ImmutablePost.Builder {}
}
```

PostEntity @Entity class here is json format:

```
 {
        "type" : "text",
        "postedBy" : {
                "username": "sandeep"
        },
        "postMedia" : {
            "mediaType": "text",
            "mediaUrl": "null",
            "content": "Hi this is testing media content",
            "createdAt": 1234,
            "updatedAt": 689
        },
        "groupEntity": {
            "groupId": 4
        }
    }
```

And Post entity class:

```
@Entity
 @Table(name = "POST")
 @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class PostEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "POST_ID")
private Long postId;

@Column(name = "POST_TYPE")
private String type;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")
private User postedBy;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_media_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private PostMedia postMedia;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName = "GROUP_ID")
private GroupEntity groupEntity;
public PostEntity() {
}
```

}

I have tried

```
objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(postEntity), ImmutablePost.class);
```

As well. but still its not working, I am facing same exception:

```
org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException: Cannot document response fields as the response body is empty

at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.AbstractFieldsSnippet.verifyContent(AbstractFieldsSnippet.java:191)
at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.AbstractFieldsSnippet.createModel(AbstractFieldsSnippet.java:147)
at org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.TemplatedSnippet.document(TemplatedSnippet.java:78)
at org.springframework.restdocs.generate.RestDocumentationGenerator.handle(RestDocumentationGenerator.java:191)
```

Comment: What is returned by the endpoint that you're making the `POST` request to? It appears to be returning a response with an empty body so there's nothing in the response to document.

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson   Actually API is return same object once it got saved. In my case I am passing entity  in request and returning Immutable Object once object got saved

Comment: It doesn't look like that's happening as the response appears to have no body. Can you provide a complete example that shows everything that's involved?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson   I have tried to put here whole flow, please let me now if you need any thing else

Comment: Thanks for the updates, but things still aren't complete. There's no `Post` class, for example, so I can't take your code and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have added Post and PostEntity kindly check and let me know How can I figure it out

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have added Post and PostEntity kindly check and let me know How can I figure it out, If you still found question is not sufficient to recreate the scenario at your end, In that case I can give you my repository access  for one day so that you can take a code pull and go though my stuff. What I have done, It really crazy for me. Mean while I am still trying.

Comment: better provide a ready-to-run project in Github. So others can quickly reproduce your problem without creating own project, copying your code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the "PostMedia" setters "PostMedia" and "GroupEntity". You need to accept strings in the setters parameter and convert them to the corresponding entity. Expecting the setter's arguments as the custom entity type is making the problem.

For example:

```
    public class MyModel {
    
        private CustomEnum myEnum;
    
        public CustomEnum getMyEnum() {
            return myEnum;
        }
    
        public void setMyEnum(String enumName) {
            this.myEnum = CustomEnum.valueOf(enumName);
        }
    
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

changing the version from 1.5.5 to 1.5.8  resolved this issue. <asciidoctor.version>1.5.8</asciidoctor.version> and having this dependency in pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```